# Big O notation for brute force solution

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am working through programming problems from InterviewCake[[1](https://www.interviewcake.com)] and this problem[[2](https://www.interviewcake.com/question/stock-price)] is confusing me.

```
 I have an array stock_prices_yesterday where:

- The indices are the time, as a number of minutes past trade 
  opening time, which was 9:30am local time.
- The values are the price of Apple stock at that time, in dollars.

For example, the stock cost $500 at 10:30am, 
so stock_prices_yesterday[60] = 500.
```

A brute force solution proposed is:

```
 The brute force ↴ approach would be to try every pair of times
 (treating the earlier time as the buy time and the later time as the 
 sell time) and see which one is best. There are n2 such combinations,
 so this will take O(n2) time.
```

I can't figure out how this solution would be O(n2).

If I have a tiny list, with stock prices, say `[21,10,43]`, then all possible combinations of this would be:

```
(21, 10)
(21, 43)
(10, 43)
(10, 21)
(43, 10)
(43, 21)
```

That is not n**2 combinations ... I am sure this is really simply but it always gets me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That is not n**2 combinations

Big-*O* notation is about the most significant factor, and the number of combinations, excluding duplicates (eg. (10, 10)) is still proportional to *n*<sup>2</sup>. In fact the total number of combinations without the duplications is *n*<sup>2</sup>-*n*. In big-*O* you only keep the most significant term, so *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

Often the set of pairs would be enumerated via

```
for i in indexes
  for j in indexes
    if i != j then
      process(i, j)
```

again for each index one is enumerated all indexes: number of indexes times the number of indexes: *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>).